# How to use checkpoints from newer TF versions using an older TF version

Tags: python, tensorflow

Is there a way to manually backwards compatibility with TF checkpoints? I need to train a model using a newer version of TF (at least 1.13.1) but the trained model has to be loaded and used by code using TF 1.12. Out of the box there is no backwards compatibility. Checkpoints from 1.13.1 cannot be loaded in 1.12. Is there some library or way to enforce compatibility or solve the incompatibility?